# Java Control Panel - Insecure JRE Versions

Tags: java, controlpanel

I don't find the below setting in my Java 1.7.0_25

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. What OS are you using, what setting are you looking for, in what environment did you find this setting before?

Comment: I cannot add snapshot unfortunately.

Comment: Try to clarify your question by responding to the questions above, we don't necessarily need a screenshot.

Comment: Win7 x64, 
I;m looking for Java control panel > Advanced > Insecure JRE Versions > If any insecure JRE Version is specified by an untrusted application ..
This settings is unavailable in this particular JRE. Where can i find this option? or is there any equivalent option to it.

Comment: refer to http://i.stack.imgur.com/b5aNS.png

Answer (score 1):

This setting has been removed, there is a new dialog / approach for these settings - details can be found on:

- http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/12/19/java-7-update-10-introduces-important-new-security-controls/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/jcp.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/client-security.html

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has overhauled the security check-boxes in the Java Control Panel after recent JRE security bugs.  You are more likely to see this..

[image]